# System Generator: a block to change sign of a floating point

Tags: fpga, xilinx, floating-point, xilinx-system-generator

I´m working with floating point numbers in System Generator. I need to perform this arithmetic operation **y = x*(-1)** . I think it could be done by using the mult block, but I don´t like this way because is very expensive in terms of FPGA demanded resources.
So I was wondering if there is any block to perform some kind of data conversión. The only thing is needed to do is to change one bit.
**Does anyone know how to change the sign a floating point number using a reasonable way?**
Thank you so much.

Comment: Interesting that this question came within hours of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9941/the-bitwise-of-a-floating-point-binary-representation.  Homework, perhaps?

Comment: More or less, is part the reflexions I have doing a undergraduate thesis project.

Comment: Really? I was starting to get the impression *we* were doing your undergraduate thesis project ;)

Answer (score 1):

Negating a floating point number involves inverting the sign bit.

(For fixed-point numbers there's a Negate block in the sysgen library which should avoid using a multiplier)

Be aware though, that sysgen is not designed for use with floating-point - you might find yourself jumping through all sorts of hoops!

Comment: No, negating a floating point number involves swapping the sign bit. The mantissa is always unsigned.  As Peterstone said, the only thing that needs to be done is change one bit.

Comment: Doh!  You're quite right - not sure what I was thinking then! All that needs inverting is the sign bit.  But not the whole bit pattern!

Comment: Yeah, "not the whole bit pattern" you are right...Sorry I´ve done that and it works more or less, even the reason it´s not clear...I take it as a provisional solution.If anybody could tell me how can acess to just one bit, the sign bit...

Comment: I corrected your answer as we discussed in the comments - You can use the "edit" link if you can add some more information or make a correction to your answer.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: Many thanks - I've added a small tweak